# HTML - Enter specified text to input

Tags: javascript, html, input

How create input in witch I can predefine text to enter in this input?
User enter website and see "Enter the text below: 'I ACCEPT'" and user have to enter this to input to contunie next page.
How define this text to enter in input?
(sry eng)

Comment: Sorry but you will have to make your question a bit more clear. It doesn't even make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is you wanted. [Fiddled here](https://jsfiddle.net/nqg1tz8v/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p>
    Type "I Accept" in the below text box to enter to our website
  </p>
  <input placeholder="Enter I accept here" id="txt" />
  <button type="button" id="btn">
    Go
  </button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (document.getElementById('txt').value.toLowerCase() === 'i accept') {

    window.open('/main/index.html');//your page
  } else {
    alert('You didnt accept our policies yet');
  }

})
```

Comment: the submit button should only work if the user enters the text "I ACCEPT"

Comment: use an if statement to check whether the user inputs the desired value

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thans